# Are 'third person singular pronouns' optional?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, indirect-speech

I took a English test in a non-English speaking country.

There was a problem with a picture. In the picture, a girl whose name is Ann says,

> My knife doesn't cut well.

The question asked: "What did Ann say?"

I had to make this direct speech into indirect one.
My answer was:

> Ann said that her knife didn't cut well.

I thought that I had perfectly answered the question, but my teacher said that I should replace 'Ann' with 'She'

- So, do I always replace a noun with a pronoun?
- Is there a rule?
- Isn't it optional to use pronouns?

Comment: That's the whole purpose for which a *pronoun* exists. Strictly speaking, your teacher is right. Colloquially speaking, both of you are right.

Comment: I lose some points because of this.............. Is there any chance to prove my answer is also right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, your teacher is wrong.  The sentence is perfectly grammatical and there is no necessity to use pronouns; it's a speaker's choice situation.

Comment: Your answer was good and would be perfectly acceptable in speech. However, it would be more naturally conversational to use the pronoun here. In my opinion, it not only avoids a jarring repetition of "Ann" but *connects* the answer to the question, Your answer could stand alone as a statement. Using 'she' confirms that you're speaking *in response* to the question, and therefore helps the conversation "flow".

Comment: @JohnLawler Repetition of proper nouns is one of the most improtant things you have to avoid in writing. This is not about grammar. I disagree with you.

Comment: @Rathony - do you have a Top Ten list?

Comment: @JHCL You can google it. Very easy to find.

Comment: @Rathony: The exercise mimics a *conversation* in which a question was asked.

Comment: @TimRomano I din't say it doesn't. I am just against repeating *proper nouns*. Are you not against?

Comment: There ***is*** a rule. In sentences like *"Ann said that Ann's feet hurt"*, I believe it would be a grammatical mistake not to use the pronoun. It certainly sounds terrible to native speakers. But in your sentence,  it's optional.

Comment: @PeterShor Can you reference a rule that stipulates what the teacher says is wrong or what the student says is right? I don't think any grammar book would spend time for a situation where everybody can say it is optional. I also think it is optional.

Comment: @Rathony: [Here](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/grammar-rules-for-he-she-usage.html) is a grammar site which gives another example where you can't repeat the proper name, quite similar to the one in may comment above: *"One would not say 'Dana lied so Dana would not have to go to school.' "*

Comment: @PeterShor 2 possibilities. You didn't understand my question or you wanted me to waste my time.

Comment: @Rathony: If I've wasted your time, I still don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean there are two sentences one is for the question and the other is for the answer

Comment: I know it is quite strange to make a repetition in a sentence. But since there are two separate sentences........... Why can I use 'Ann' again......?

Comment: How did you know the girl's name was Anne? Were there more than two people in the picture? Was there a sign above the girl's head telling you her name? If for example there were two girls, and only Anne had spoken, then you must mention the name of the person *who* spoke. If you asked person B what Anne said, then person B would only use the pronoun, *she*. Could you not scan and upload the image?

Comment: there were two people in the picture but it was not a girl, it was a boy whose name is Jake.

Comment: There is no rule that you had to use "she" rather than "Ann".  In some cases "she" would be more "natural", but even then there's no requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, two occurrences of the same name aren't used this close to one another. Consider the following two sentences:

- John went home. John turned on the TV.

This sounds *marked* to most speakers. (NOTE: markedness is not the same as ungrammaticality). The reason it sounds marked is because there are ***collocation restrictions*** on names.

These restrictions occur because of a general rule, as Kent Bach notes:

> "We generally choose the least informative sort of expression whose
>   use will enable the hearer to identify the individual we wish to refer
>   to" (see p. 9 of [this](http://userwww.sfsu.edu/kbach/referring.pdf))

Pronouns are less informative than names. So if a name has just been used, we usually use the pronoun, since the fact that the name has just been used gives us enough information to figure out the referent of the pronoun.

Your teacher seems to be confusing the markedness of your response with its ungrammaticality. If it's a class which is trying to teach you how to be conversationally fluent, she might be justified in giving you partial credit, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Nine times out of ten, in a conversation between native speakers, a question that uses a personal name, such as

**What did Ann say?**

will receive a reply that begins like this:

**She said ...**

or begins simply like this, as a fragment:

**that ...**

However, it is perfectly grammatical (as John Lawler remarks) for the reply to begin with the proper noun, and for the reply to be a complete sentence, replete with tense-shifting to mark indirect speech, though I'd guess such tense shifting is used about half the time.

Comment: At what level do you think the OP is in terms of learning English? The OP just wants to find if it is the right way to repeat the proper noun and see if he can recover a few points he might lose for repeating it. . I would say, "No, it is wrong. You have to use the pronoun."  (I flagged this question off-topic)

Comment: @Rathony - why did you repeat 'the OP' in this comment?

Comment: @JHCL Because I don't know whether the OP is he or she. Is it wrong?

Comment: Err, you used 'he' later on. No I don't think it's wrong, but it seems to contradict your argument.

Comment: @JHCL Exactly. I used *he* in order not to repeat the pronoun. That's the good writing, I guess.